# Use a same function for several location within a code for C

Tags: c, function

How to create a seperate function for the Continue or Stop so can always refer to there. below not a proper C but just an idea what to achieve

```
main()
    do{ 
        request for input...
          if found invalid, Continue or stop?
           ...
        After one complete run
           ask again for Continue or stop?
           ...
    }while(Continue)
```

I have tried this, but the value from the feed,Continue can't pass to the main function. is there something wrong with my logic or there is more simpler ways to do this.

```
struct Ans {
    int Continue;
    int Stop;
    char choice;
};

struct Ans feed ;
void YesNo(){
    int p=1;
    int q=2;
    char choice;
    feed.Continue=0;
    feed.Stop=0;
    while (feed.Continue==0)
    {
        printf("\nDo you wish to try again (Type Y to continue Q to quit:");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);
        choice = toupper(choice);
        if(choice == 'Y')
        {
            feed. Continue = p;
            return;

        }
        else if(choice=='Q') {

            feed.Stop = q;
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            printf("\nError: Invalid choice\n");
            do
            {
                feed.choice = getchar();

            } while (feed.choice != '\n' && feed.choice != EOF);
        }
    }

}
void main{        
Loop:do{
    printf("Please enter(k):\n");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    struct Ans feed;
    char str[N];
    if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin))
    {
        flag = 0;

            long value;
            char *check; 

            value = strtol(str, &check, 0);

            if (!isspace(*check) && *check != 0) flag = 1;
            {
                printf("\nInvalid Input\n");

            }

            while ( flag == 1)
            {
                YesNo();
                flag = 0;
                {
                    if (feed.Continue) {
                        goto Loop;
                    }
                    else if (feed.Stop) exit(0);
                }
            }

        }

        if ((k<0)||(k>N-1)) {
            printf("Input value out of range");
        }
        YesNo();
        {
            if (feed.Continue) {
                goto Loop;
            }
            else if (feed.Stop) exit(0);

        }



        //run something

        do{
            printf("\nDo you wish to try again (Type Y to continue Q to quit:");
            scanf(" %c", &choice);
            choice = toupper(choice);
        }while((choice != 'Y') &&  (choice != 'Q'));

    }while(choice == 'Y');

        return ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Describe more detail what do you want, it isn't clear now

Comment: How on earth is this valid C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make ContinueOrStop function outside the main function and then call in main when you need like

```
void ContinueORStop()
{
  do{ 
        request for input...
          if found invalid, Continue or stop?
           ...
        After one complete run
           ask again for Continue or stop?
           ...
    }while(Continue)
}

main()
{
  ContinueOrStop();
}
```